# Jwsc task in ant does not consider fork and compiler type setting

Tags: java, ant

I have been using ant scripts to build web service ear files making use of jwsc task. While building too many war files in one for loop, the following error is encountered.

> C:\Work\build.xml:193: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1136)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1307)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1362)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1323)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1076)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:101)
>           at weblogic.wsee.util.JAXWSClassLoaderFactory$1.findClass(JAXWSClassLoaderFactory.java:52)
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:86)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>           at weblogic.descriptor.internal.DescriptorImpl.createRootBean(DescriptorImpl.java:386)
>           at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptorRoot(BasicDescriptorManager.java:396)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.war.WebAppProcessor.getWebAppBean(WebAppProcessor.java:98)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.war.WebAppProcessor.process(WebAppProcessor.java:47)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.process.CompositeProcessor.process(CompositeProcessor.java:47)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.buildWebServices(JwsCompiler.java:532)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.build.JwsCompiler.compile(JwsCompiler.java:493)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.generate(JwsModule.java:379)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:256)
>           at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:184)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)

As per suggestions on some sites, i used the fork setting in the task along with memoryinitialsize and memorymaximumsize. But i still encounter the error as jwsc is not considering the fork option. The loop only fails after building 5 war files. From the previous loop output, i could grab this snippet from cmd.

```
 [jwsc] Parsing source files
 [jwsc] Parsing source files
 [jwsc] 1 JWS files being processed for module TESTService
 [jwsc] JWS: C:\Work\Build\WEB-INF\classes\TESTServiceImpl.java Validated.
 [jwsc] Processing 1 JAX-WS web services...
 [jwsc] Since compiler setting isn't classic or modern, ignoring fork setting.
 [jwsc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pmraju\AppData\Local\Temp\_h40kgy
 [jwsc] Since compiler setting isn't classic or modern, ignoring fork setting.
```

Here is my ant sample code using jwsc

```
        <taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </taskdef>

        <jwsc fork="yes" compiler="modern" srcdir="${destdir}/Build/WEB-INF/classes" destdir="${destdir}/Build" memoryinitialsize="1024m" memorymaximumsize="2048m" optimize="on" includeantruntime="false">
            <module contextpath="/${service}" name="${service}" explode="false">
                <jws file="${service}Impl.java" compiledwsdl="${destdir}/Build/${service}.jar" type="JAXWS" />
            </module>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </jwsc>
```

From the above it can be seen that even if i provide **fork** and **compiler** attributes, the jwsc output states **[jwsc] Since compiler setting isn't classic or modern, ignoring fork setting.**

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** 
Have been able to proceed without *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen* error by running the command `set ANT_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` in cmd before invoking ant. I still could not figure why the compiler setting is not considered inside jwsc task, hopefully someone would figure.

Comment: What version of ant are you using?  It looks like this *might* have been fixed in Ant 1.7.1 for some cases: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41280

Comment: @David: I am currently using Ant 1.9.4, and i went through the link, but i feel it was fixed as part of apt task alone, also the support page for jwsc does not give information about specifying compiler type.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webserv/anttasks.html#wp1069899). I wonder if there is another way to invoke fork settings or set the compiler setting stick.